# Can $p$ Adic Integers Be Expressed as Fractals?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory, fractals

In the book "A Course in $p$ Adic Analysis" by Alain M Robert, he describes how the $p$ adic integers can be expressed as fractals.  For example, $\mathbb{Z}_3$ can be expressed as a Sierpińsky gasket shown below.

[image]

But the $p$ adic integers apparently can form more complex fractals.  For example, here is an example of $\mathbb{Z}_5$:

[image]

How exactly does this work? The author does give explanations about the work behind the different models, but I am just confused how $\mathbb{Z}_p$ can be expressed in this way at an elementary level.  What exactly is going on here intuitively?

Additionally, if someone could point me to resources that elaborate on this subject (ie $p$ adic integers and their relation to fractals) that would be amazing.

Comment: It becomes harder and harder to show in Euclidean geometry, as $p$ gets bigger, but the sets $p\mathbb Z_p,$ $1+p\mathbb Z_p,\cdots,(p-1)+p\mathbb Z_p$ partition $\mathbb Z_p$ into $p$ subsets, each of which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p.$ The parts of the partition are pairwise discrete, in that $|x-y|_p=1$ if $x,y$ are in disjoint parts. The parts are also open in $\mathbb Z_p.$

Comment: Some visualization ideas for $p$-adics: https://www.thekerneltrip.com/python/p-addic-numbers-visualization/, https://mathoverflow.net/q/51905/27465, http://www.nt.th-koeln.de/fachgebiete/mathe/knospe/p-adic/, https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-the-towering-p-adic-numbers-work-20201019/

Comment: See Albert Cuoco's article "Visualizing the $p$-adic Integers" in the 1991 American Mathematical Monthly. All of this can be done in the plane, no need for higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

A $p$-adic integer can be written as $$x = \sum_{m=0}^\infty x_m p^m$$ where each $x_m \in \{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$.  If you want to map this into $\mathbb R^d$, take $p$ distinct vectors
${\bf v}_0, \ldots, {\bf v}_{p-1} \in \mathbb R^d$ and a constant $0 < c \le 1/p$, and map $$x  \mapsto \sum_{m=0}^\infty  c^m {\bf v}_{x_m}$$
The map will be continuous; at least if $c$ is small enough, it should be one-to-one (I'll leave the details to you).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this makes a lot more sense to me now!